# Can't get Symfony Authentication to work

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I've been working on a Symfony project and the authentication process is becoming a headache. It seems the configuration files are OK, but when I test, the login page just refreshes an does not authenticate, but it doesn't show any errors either. Someone can help me figure out what I'm missing here?

My security.yml file is like this (I'm using md5 because I'm working on a legacy user base and the %app.locale% I just added because I was thinking maybe the locale prefix in routes was causing this problem):

```
security:
    access_denied_url: 403
    encoders:
        PsicoBundle\Entity\Usuario:
            algorithm: md5
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 0

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: PsicoBundle:Entity:Usuario

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: /%app.locales%/login
                check_path: /%app.locales%/login
                default_target_path: /%app.locales%/dashboard
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path: /%app.locales%/logout
                target: /%app.locales%/login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/%app.locales%/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /%app.locales%/manage, roles: ROLE_SUPER }
        - { path: /%app.locales%/dashboard, roles: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SUPER] }
```

This is how my User Entity looks like:

```
<?php

namespace PsicoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
//use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuarios")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PsicoBundle\Repository\UsuarioRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *  
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */

class Usuario implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Expose
     */
    private $nome;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="senha")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="endereco")
     */
    private $endereco;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15, name="telefone")
     */
    private $telefone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=15, name="celular")
     */
    private $celular;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cidade")
     */
    private $cidade;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Idioma")
     */
    private $idioma;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", name="email")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @Expose
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $ativo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="TipoUsuario", inversedBy="usuarios")
     */
    private $tiposUsuario;


    public function __construct() {
        $this->ativo = true;
        $this->tiposUsuario = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setUsername($username) {
        $this->email = $username;
    }

    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email) {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getPassword() {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function isEnabled() {
        return $this->ativo;
    }


    public function setAtivo($ativo) {
        $this->ativo = $ativo;
    }

    public function getRoles() {
        return $this->tiposUsuario->toArray();
    }

    public function getPermissao() {
        return $this->tiposUsuario;
    }

    public function getNome() {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function setNome($nome) {
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            $this->ativo,
            $this->tiposUsuario
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            $this->ativo,
            $this->tiposUsuario
            ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    public function getSalt() {
        return null;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials() {

    }

    public function setRoles($tiposUsuario) {
        $this->tiposUsuario = $tiposUsuario;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEndereco()
    {
        return $this->endereco;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $endereco
     */
    public function setEndereco($endereco)
    {
        $this->endereco = $endereco;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTelefone()
    {
        return $this->telefone;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $telefone
     */
    public function setTelefone($telefone)
    {
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCelular()
    {
        return $this->celular;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $celular
     */
    public function setCelular($celular)
    {
        $this->celular = $celular;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCidade()
    {
        return $this->cidade;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $cidade
     */
    public function setCidade($cidade)
    {
        $this->cidade = $cidade;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTiposUsuario()
    {
        return $this->tiposUsuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $tiposUsuario
     */
    public function setTiposUsuario($tiposUsuario)
    {
        $this->tiposUsuario = $tiposUsuario;
    }


    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIdioma()
    {
        return $this->idioma;
    }


    /**
     * @param mixed $idioma
     */
    public function setIdioma($idioma)
    {
        $this->idioma = $idioma;
    }

}
```

I also have the Repository class to query the user by its e-mail, tha follows:

```
 <?php

namespace PsicoBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UsuarioRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u, g')
            ->from('PsicoBundle:Usuario', 'u')
            ->leftJoin('u.tiposUsuario', 'g')
            ->where('u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('email', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

        if (null == $user) {
            $message = sprintf('Usuário com credencial "%s" não encontrado', $username);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message);
        }

        return $user;
    }


}
```

And my form is like this:

```html
        <form class="m-t" role="form" action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post" id="login-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" required="" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'field.password'|trans }}" required="" name="_password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" name="login">Login</button>

            <p class="text-muted text-center"><small>{{ 'login.calltoaction.text'|trans }}</small></p>
            <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="{{ path('cadastro_gratis') }}">{{ 'login.testbutton.text'|trans }}</a>
        </form>
```

The symfony's debug information window show that I'm legged in as anon. And the only thing dev's log shows me is this:

```
   [2016-12-14 10:59:16] request.INFO: Matched route "{route}". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"fe495d","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/_wdt/fe495d","method":"GET"} []
[2016-12-14 11:04:51] request.INFO: Matched route "{route}". {"route":"login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"PsicoBundle\\Controller\\SecurityController::loginAction","_locale":"en","_route":"login"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/en/login","method":"POST"} []
[2016-12-14 11:04:51] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2016-12-14 11:04:52] request.INFO: Matched route "{route}". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"b4915e","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://localhost:8000/_wdt/b4915e","method":"GET"} []
```

I have an user in my database to test it, and this user has both of the Roles.
Can someone help me in this? Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out what I was doing wrong. In My security.yml I was using the /%app.locales%/ parameter defined in my config.yml as pt_BR|en|es when I should've matched the routes prefix I set in rounting.yml - {_locale) - changed the prefix in my security file routes and authentication went back to normal.

And also had to take the annotation routes from my controller and insert it in routing.yml

So my routing now is:

```
psico:
    resource: "@PsicoBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    requirements:
        _locale: "%app.locales%"

login:
    path: /{_locale}/login
    defaults: { _controller: PsicoBundle:Security:login}
    requirements:
        _locale: "%app.locales%"

logout:
    path: /{_locale}/logout
    defaults: { _controller: PsicoBundle:Security:logout}
    requirements:
        _locale: "%app.locales%"
```

And my Security is:

```
security:
access_denied_url: 403
encoders:
    PsicoBundle\Entity\Usuario:
        algorithm: md5
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations: 0

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: PsicoBundle:Usuario
            property: email

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            default_target_path: /dashboard
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
        logout:
            path: logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: /manage, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: /dashboard, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Thank you, @MohamedBenHenda for helping me trying to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you used two user provider `in_memory` and `our_db_provider`

Try to delete the block of the `in_memory` user provider

```
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: PsicoBundle:Entity:Usuario
```

Comment: Hello Mohamed, removed in_memory, cleared cache and restarted the server, got the same behavior.

Comment: Has the user a  ROLE_SUPER role?

Comment: Can you debug the user in the login page? In twig {{ dump(app.user)}}

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, Mohamed. Debuging app.user in twig I get a null, but when I run the query from my repository directly in my controller I get the object with both Roles. I'm following this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html 

I believe symfony is not querying the users datatable.

Comment: To querying thes users from database, you should use the FOSUserBundle (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) and setup the setting for this bundle.

Comment: I'll take a look in this bundle. But the most strange thing is that I have an app with that same approach implemented. The only difference is that in the other app i did not change the bundle name and it was single language o_O